# Requisição AJAX com JavaScript puro (sem APIs)

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser

Geralmente, quando precisamos recorrer à requisições **AJAX** usando JavaScript, temos à mão APIs que nos auxiliam com isso (ex: **jQuery**).

Porém, qual seria a maneira mais segura e **cross-browser** de realizar essas requisições (POST e GET) usando **JavaScript puro**?

Comment: Obs: Movi a parte de suporte cross-domain para outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisicao-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis

Comment: Eu usava isso antes de descobrir o jquery. Depois que veio essa maravilha, felizmente, não precisamos mais nos preocupar com essa questão do cross-browser, o código fica mais limpo. Quem evolui o jquery que vai se preocupar com isso. Recomendo que use ajax com jquery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Com as novas APIs dos navegadores, ao invés de usar `XMLHttpRequest`, podemos usar a API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) para realizar requisições HTTP assíncronas.

O uso de `fetch` é bem mais simples se comparado ao seu antecessor. Além disso, a API em questão usa [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), o que é significativamente interessante, tendo em vista que podemos usar `async`/`await` se desejarmos.

Para demonstrar como funciona, vamos acessar a [API do GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/):

```js
const baseurl = 'https://api.github.com/users'
const username = 'lffg'

fetch(`${baseurl}/${username}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(`O usuário ${data.login} tem ${data.public_repos} repositórios públicos.`)
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Whoops! Erro:', error.message || error))
```

Também é possível notar na linha 5 do exemplo anterior que a API `fetch` nos fornece também modos de transformar a resposta ([`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)) da requisição em JSON ([`Response.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)), texto ([`Response.text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)) e diversos outros os quais você pode consultar [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#methods).

Sobre os diversos tipos que se pode passar ao corpo da requisição HTTP, ler [Quais os principais tipos aceitos pela API Fetch para o corpo da requisição HTTP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/494070/69296).

#### Compatibilidade entre *browsers* antigos

A API `fetch` já é relativamente bem suportada. [Consulte a tabela de compatibilidade.](https://caniuse.com/fetch)

Se você pretende suportar alguma versão ou navegador que ainda não a suporta, pode utilizar um *polyfill*. Você pode encontrar diversos, como [este](https://github.com/github/fetch).

Comment: Muito bom o update! De fato atualmente é a maneira mais recomendada

Answer (score 54):

O site [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/) possui um [exemplo completo](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html) de requisição Ajax destinada a funcionar na maioria dos browsers (atuais e antigos), sem o uso de bibliotecas externas:

```js
function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
    var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
    if (!req) return;
    var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
    req.open(method,url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    if (postData)
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
//          alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
            return;
        }
        callback(req);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
}

var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

function createXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        }
        catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

A parte "padronizada" (i.e. suportada por navegadores recentes, que seguem os padrões estabelecidos) é a que envolve o [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest). As demais, estão aí para dar suporte a navegadores antigos.

Fonte: [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557268/520779) no SOEN

Comment: +1 E quanto ao caso de requisições cross-domain? Essa abordagem suportaria de forma cross-browser?

Comment: @EvertonAgner Eu acho que a questão cross-domain merece uma pergunta em si. É muito mais complicada. Você tem várias opções: [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/), JSONP, proxy

Comment: @EvertonAgner Isso que o Juan Mendes falou. Em algumas dessas soluções (ex.: CORS) não é preciso mexer nada no código, ele funciona do mesmo jeito pro mesmo domínio e pra domínios externos; o que tem que mexer é na configuração do servidor (indicando que ele aceita Ajax para outros domínios). Outras (ex.: JSONP) precisam de código próprio pra isso. Ou seja, assunto para uma outra pergunta...

Comment: Feito! http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisicao-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis

Answer (score 15):

```
try
{
    var loader = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch (err)
{
    // versões antigas do Internet Explorer não tem a classe XMLHttpRequest, precisa usar esse componente ActiveX
    var loader = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

loader.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    // esse callback é chamado várias vezes para cada mudança de readyState
    // readyState 4 é chamado quando o request é concluído (mesmo que .done() do jQuery)
    // você também pode checar o this.status para ver código de retorno HTTP
    // 200 é sucesso
    // 404 é página não encontrada
    // 403 é acesso negado
    // 500 é erro interno do servidor etc
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
}
loader.open('POST', 'http://www.exemple.com/submit.php', true);
loader.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
loader.send('nome=Manoel&idade=50'); // use null para métodos que não forem POST
```

Answer (score 11):

A requisição AJAX em Javascript puro é feita com o objeto `XMLHttpRequest`. A menos que você queira usar uma versão antiga do Internet Explorer, por exemplo, que usava um objeto `ActiveX`. Então, costuma-se começar com esse "quickfix":

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if(window.ActiveXObject) xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
else throw "AJAX não suportado!";
```

Depois, você precisa escutar ao evento `onreadystatechange` do seu objeto XMLHttpRequest:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // Download concluído e a resposta não contém erros
        return this.responseText; // this dentro dessa function é seu XMLHttpRequest
    }
    // Você pode colocar outras condições aqui, como responder com erro quando o status for 404 ou 500, por exemplo
}
```

E finalmente iniciar o request:

```
xmlhttp.open(metodo, url, true);
// metodo: "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"... enfim, um suportado pelo HTTP
// url: a URL do seu request
// o terceiro argumento é o 'A' do AJAX. True = request assíncrono; False = request síncrono.
loader.send(queryString); // quesyString é opcional
```

Answer (score 8):

Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
try{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch(ee){
    try{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }catch(e){
        try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(E){
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
}

function pegarCep( CEP ){
    if( CEP.length==0) return false;
    var divCep = document.getElementById('divCep');
    divCep.innerHTML = "Carregando...";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/cadastro-sms/br/cep.asp?CEP="+ CEP,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            var resposta = xmlhttp.responseText;
            divCep.innerHTML = resposta;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);             
}
```