# Como efetuar requisições Ajax, com Jquery, em domínios diferentes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

É possível realizarmos uma requisição do tipo POST a uma url que não faz parte do domínio da nossa aplicação?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.dominioexterno.com.br/acao/",
    data: {
        var1: $('#input1').val(),
        var2: $('#input2').val(),
    }
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("OK");
});
```

Estou tentando fazer algo parecido com isso, porém o que obtenho é um "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Como resolver esse tipo de problema?

Answer (score 13):

É possível habilitar as requisições CORS no navegador fazendo uso do jQuery com o seguinte código:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Estas requisições entre dominios diferentes por muito tempo representaram algumas brechas de segurança, portanto os navegadores passaram a desabiltar essa funcionalidade por padrão. Atualmente os navegadores modernos (Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, e Chrome) permitem esse tipo de requisição, **desde que o Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) também esteja habilitada no servidor**.

Uma excelente referência sobre o assunto pode ser encontrada no seguinte endereço:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2327-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-AJAX-Requests-Between-jQuery-And-Node-js.htm

Outra excelente referência sobre como habilitar o CORS pode ser encontrada nesta pergunta:

- [Requisição Ajax cross-domain com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisicao-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)

Comment: Para o CORS funcionar, o servidor também precisa estar configurado para aceitar os headers que o JS vai enviar.

Comment: Essa solução depende de muitas pré-condições. A melhor forma de fazer isso é criar uma entrada no servidor da aplicação que faz essa requisição (via `curl` ou similares) e retorna os dados.

Answer (score 7):

Quando o assunto é CORS, "incompatibilidade" e restrições são algo que não podemos deixar de lado.

Um modo alternativo é utilizar um arquivo php como intermediário, fazendo um papel de proxy.

Você pode usar CURL:

```
<?php
//Proxy.php

$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'http://www.dominioexterno.com.br/acao/';

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US,en,pt;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('param' => 'value'));

$reponse = curl_exec( $curl );

curl_close( $curl );

echo $reponse;
```

> `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);`
>   Aqui a requisição foi definida como POST
>
> `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('param' => 'value'));`. 
>   e aqui são os parâmetros `param=value`

Answer (score 0):

Qual o conteúdo que retorna desta requisição?
Você poderia utilizar jsonp, assim você consegue fazer requisições cross-domain;

Para ver como isso funciona, você pode ver:
https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Comment: Sua resposta veio parar na análise de "Publicações de baixa qualidade". Não merece voto para deletar porque além do link você menciona um par de palavras-chave importantes. Se quiser aprender o que é uma resposta de qualidade é só conferir a dos colegas aqui encima.

Answer (score 0):

Olá utilize conforme o exemplo que segue abaixo: ( [site jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) )

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="images"></div>

<script>
(function() {
  var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
        $( "<img>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#images" );
        if ( i === 3 ) {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```