# Como pegar o retorno JSON via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-service

Tenho um link do *Click to Call* que me retorna um JSON. Como proceder para pegar os dados gerados em JSON via jQuery?

Link:

```
http://192.168.0.6:8080/G4FlexWS/rest/flexuc/clicktocall/ext/telefoneOrigem/telefoneOrigem/telefoneDestino
```

Retorno em JSON:

```
{"acctid":"1401278513.28186", "status": "0", "erro":"" }
```

Comment: Se tu já tentou algo edite a pergunta postando o código.

Comment: Você usa asp.net C#?

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando o [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).
Por exemplo:

```
$.getJSON("http://192.168.0.6:8080/G4FlexWS/rest/flexuc/clicktocall/ext/telefoneOrigem/telefoneOrigem/telefoneDestino", function(data) {

    alert( data.acctid );

});
```

Comment: ja tentei assim, mas ele não retorna

Comment: ele não retorna, porque estou tendo um problema de cross-domain

Comment: @JohnatanDantas Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12363/como-efetuar-requisicoes-ajax-com-jquery-em-dominios-diferentes

Answer (score 2):

Tem diversas formas, segue dois exemplos:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'sua-url',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {seus-dados},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var acctid = data.acctid
        var status = data.status
        ....
    }
```

ou

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sua-url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: seus-dados,
        success: function(data)
       {
            var response = $.parseJSON(data); 
            var acctid = response.acctid
            var status = response.status
            ....
        }
```