# Pegando informações de um site via jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso pegar informações de um site a cada X minutos.
Estou testando localmente com um HTML fixo mas a idéia é fazer um request a cada X minutos, obter as informacoes e salvá-las de alguma forma. 
Vi em algumas perguntas aqui no site que não é possivel fazer um GET via localhost para um dominio diferente do seu... Isso é possível se eu fizer o upload para meu server?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     //make a request 

     //update the data
     updateData();

     //save somewhere

     reload(10000);

     function reload(time){
        setInterval(function(){
           //make a request 

           //update the data
           updateData();

        }, time);
     }

     function updateData(){
        var table = $('#discount_card_list tbody');
        var totalCards = $('#discount_card_list .card').text();
        var biggestDiscountRow = 0;
        var biggestDiscount = 0.00;

        table.find('tr').each( function(rowIndex, r) {
           var seller = $(this).find('.seller').text(); 
           //discard ebay seller
           if (seller.toLowerCase().indexOf("ebay") >= 0){
              //go to the next iteration and discard the line
              return true;
           }

           var discount = $(this).find('.save').text().replace('%', '');

           if(discount > biggestDiscount) {
              biggestDiscount = discount;
              biggestDiscountRow = $(this);
           }
        });

        console.log('Date: ' + new Date($.now()));
        console.log('Cards: ' + totalCards.trim());
        console.log('Quantity: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.quantity').text().trim());
        console.log('Card type: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.type').text().trim());
        console.log('Card value: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.value').text().trim());
        console.log('Price: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.cost').text().trim());
        console.log('Save: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.save').text().trim());
        console.log('Shipping: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.shipping').text().trim());
        console.log('Seller: ' + biggestDiscountRow.find('.seller').text().trim());
        console.log('---------------------------');
     }
  });
```

Comment: Sim, para ativar requisições para outros servidores você tem que ativar o CORS.

Comment: Para isso ocorrer esse servidor tem que permitir o CORS?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12363/como-efetuar-requisições-ajax-com-jquery-em-dom%C3%ADnios-diferentes

Comment: E também http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis