# Pedido cross-origin bloqueado

Tags: javascript, html, json, web-service

Estou a usar uma API da Elsevier para ir buscar uma listagem de livros. Para fazer isso, estou a usar um exemplo deles presente neste link: http://apihtmlgen.elasticbeanstalk.com/sd_search.html 
Fiz o meu registo, tenho a minha APIkey e tenho o seguinte código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Elsevier ScienceDirect Search via APIs</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<script>
var xsl="";
var xml="";

function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    else {
        //alert ("in ActiveXObject ELSE condition");
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
    xml="";
    var key="20d0c__________________________adb"; // API key value
    document.getElementById("sd_results").innerHTML="";

//alert("in displayResult()");
var x = document.getElementById("form1");
var val = x.elements[0].value;

var apiReq="http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query="+val+"&apiKey="+key+"&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml";

if (xsl == "") {
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("sd_results_webkit.xsl");
}

//alert('getting xml');
xml=loadXMLDoc(apiReq);

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    var ex='';
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("sd_results").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("sd_results").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }

}

function formReset() {
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
}

function displayPage(link) {
    xml="";
    document.getElementById("sd_results").innerHTML="";

var apiReq=link;

if (xsl == "") {
    xsl=loadXMLDoc("sd_results_webkit.xsl");
}

//alert('getting xml');
xml=loadXMLDoc(apiReq);

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    var ex='';
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("sd_results").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("sd_results").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }

}
</script>
<title>Elsevier ScienceDirect Search API</title>
</head>
<body onload="formReset();return false;">
<form id="form1" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
<b>Please enter search keywords separated by space:</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="query" style="width:200px"/></form>
<input type="submit" onclick="displayResult();return false;" value="Search" />

<div id="sd_results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

O que acontece, é que ao fazer o pedido dá-me o seguinte erro "Pedido Cross-Origin bloqueado":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este erro está haver com o que? Eu estou a fazer este pedido no link que foi registado, tudo direitinho. Do que será este erro?

Comment: Culpa do CORS. Tenta definir nas configurações do seu servidor `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` ou trocando o asterisco pelo URL que você está tentando acessar. Enviar um *Request Header* do tipo *Origin* pelo JavaScrip pode ser necessário também.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, vou procurar isso e já dou o feedback. obrigado

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, isso é colocado nas configurações do servidor? no meu caso estou a usar o cpanel. Ou é colocado num ficheiro .htaccess?

Comment: Eu sei que a culpa é do CORS, mas eu nunca vivenciei o problema. Veja se [esse artigo](https://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working) te ajuda

Comment: @BrunoAugusto como enviar um request(GET) sem ser do tipo Origin? eu só quero resgatar a resposta de uma página php enviando um id só que é outro dominio, to usando XHR também, o que fazer?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: [Como efetuar requisições Ajax, com Jquery, em domínios diferentes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12363/91)

Answer (score 1):

Essa resposta é mais um comentário grande para, talvez, ajudar o OP e o outro usuário com o mesmo problema.

---

Os meus contatos com APIs ao longo desses anos foram bem poucos, então pode até ser que seja necessário fazer algo a mais.

Bem... O mais próximo que eu consegui de uma Requisição de sucesso foi por [usar JSONP](http://jsfiddle.net/4gkw2jLq/).

A Requisição é feita e um XML é retornado por ser o padrão da API, mas por ter sido definido explicitamente JSONP, a jQuery tenta analisar o corpo de resposta, gerando um Syntax Error afinal JSON é JSON e XML é XML.

E enviar qualquer *Request Header* ou definir o argumento **httpAccept** reconhecido pela API ao que parece também é ignorado pela jQuery.

Eu até tentei fazer um "XMLP", segundo uns tópicos no SOEN, alterando o **dataType** para:

```
dataType: 'jsonp xml'
```

Mas também sem sucesso.

Sem usar JSONP o browser envia automaticamente o cabeçalho **Origin** com o endereço de onde a Requisição está partindo, mas o retorno está sendo um Status 500 pois, aparentemente, o servidor da Elsevier não está configurado para aceitar requisições *crossdomain* pois não está enviando o cabeçalho **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** com um *wildcard* (*) como valor.

Assim, toda e qualquer requisição que não parta do servidor da API, falha.

Apesar de conhecer o CORS, o conheço superficialmente e, como [me parece](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) que ele é fundamentado no objeto XmlHttpRequest creio ser algo exclusivo do JavaScript.

Supondo que assim seja, sugiro que, caso ninguém mais possa lhe ajudar, você use uma linguagem do lado servidor para consumir essa API e, talvez, use o JS para requisitar os dados assíncronamente a partir da sua própria aplicação.

Se você tiver algum exemplo funcional de consumo dessa API, ajudaria a compreender o que se passa.

Comment: então, se fizer o pedido do lado do servidor, por exemplo usando php, como posso fazer? tenho muita pouca experiência neste tipo de casos. obrigado

Comment: Isso já foge um pouco do escopo do tópico mas uma vez que ao que parece é uma API bem simples perfeitamente configurável por parâmetros GET, um file_get_contents() resolve. Daí você lê a resposta, manipula se necessário (JSON é mais fácil) e ecoa algo pro JS trabalhar. Se não precisar manipular pode ecoar diretamente o que você receber como resposta, XMl ou JSON, você quem sabe.