# Requisições cross-origin estão sendo bloqueadas

Tags: angularjs, web-service, api, cors

Preciso consultar alguns CEPs na API viacep (https://viacep.com.br), quando executo o get abaixo:

```
  vm.buscarCEP = function(){
    const cep = vm.empresaResponsavel.cep //RECEBE CEP DO CAMPO
    const apiViaCep = `http://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`
    $http.get(apiViaCep).then(function(resp) { //CONSULTA NA API
      vm.empresaResponsavel.logradouro = resp.data.logradouro
      vm.empresaResponsavel.bairro = resp.data.bairro
      vm.empresaResponsavel.cidade = resp.data.localidade
      vm.empresaResponsavel.uf = resp.data.uf
    }).catch(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp.data.errors)
      console.log("CEP NÃO RECONHECIDO.")
    })
  }
```

Recebo o seguinte erro no console do navegador:

```
Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://viacep.com.br/ws/89700128/json/. (Motivo: símbolo 'authorization' faltando no cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' durante a pré-conexão CORS).
```

Estou utilizando AngularJS e Express/Node.

Abaixo um trecho onde valido o usuário e passo para o backend um cabeçalho com o token do mesmo, para verificar se continua o mesmo. Estou achando que pode ser esse cabeçalho o problema.

```
function validateUser() {
  const user = auth.getUser()
  const authPage = '/auth.html'
  const isAuthPage = $window.location.href.includes(authPage)

  if (!user && !isAuthPage) {
    $window.location.href = authPage
  } else if (user && !user.isValid) {
    auth.validateToken(user.token, (err, valid) => {
      if (!valid) {
        $window.location.href = authPage
      } else {
        user.isValid = true
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = user.token
        isAuthPage ? $window.location.href = '/' : $location.path('/dashboard')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: creio que esse link pode de ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41322/pedido-cross-origin-bloqueado

Comment: @renan.menesesUFC não sei como JSONP (que parece ser a principal proposta da resposta que linkou) ajudaria nesse problema especifico, para Express (um framework para Nodejs que roda no back-end) já tem libs que resolvem, como o https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors (existem outras). O caso ai é só saber configurar, daria até para fazer na mão: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Answer (score -1):

Adicione o cors:

```
npm install cors --save
```

No node js adicione esse código

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Não deu certo ://

Comment: Você pode fazer um teste?
Adiciona esse plugin no navegador ?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=pt-BR&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela ajuda!! É só habilitar e efetuar o teste? Fiz isso, retornou o mesmo erro. Efetuei o teste também com outra api, a da tabela fipe: http://fipeapi.appspot.com/ e além do erro anterior, retornou com HTTP status code 405.

Comment: A principio sim. O Status 405 é que o método não está habilitado, o que não faz o menor sentido ... Vou fazer um teste aqui pegando alguns dados dessas API's e depois te dou um parecer de o que aconteceu.

Comment: Fred, cria um outro projeto qualquer dá um npm install axios --save e vê se ele faz a requisição...  Rodei pelo node aqui e consegui pegar os dados das duas API's.

var axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

    let cep = '89261765';

axios.get(`http://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

Comment: Em outro projeto eu recebi também. Porém neste não. Creio que sei prq está acontecendo esse erro quando tento conectar a API. Inclui um bloco de código na pergunta, são as rotas depois da autenticação no sistema, estou usando JWT.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77167/discussion-between-fred-and-lucas-brogni).

Comment: Tente utilizar extensão do Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=pt-BR que permite o Cors. Isso é uma questão de estar local.

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema ao criar a minha api, a diferença é que uso Angular 8 ao invés de AngularJS, você pode instalar o cors com `npm install cors` e utilizar a seguinte configuração no node

```
const cors = require('cors');
[...]
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://origin-angular-example.com:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
[...]
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

*[...] são espaços em seu código caso houver...*

Além disso você pode tentar instalar essa extensão: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc no seu navegador e habilite-a.