# Problema com json

Tags: javascript, json, aplicação-web

Por que não estou conseguindo recuperar esse json no web service da api que estou usando.

```
var url = "https://api.roomorama.com/v1.0/rooms.json?access_token=RS97GGOxoeuo66dXwF4UcHhjmgKjUnAjDiBVDAVTo";  
function preenche(){
     $.getJSON(url, function(dados){
        //log para mostrar quando o getJson funcionou
        $('.greeting-thumbnail').append(" 1234");
     });
}
```

Comment: Problema de CORS, vai ter de usar JSONP, mas não sei se o servidor aceita... vou olhar de novo mais logo. Pode ser que outros ajudem entretanto.

Comment: Essa questão é recorrente aqui do SOpt. [Veja esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12363/) e suas vinculadas. 
Resumindo, você pode *tentar* usar `jQuery.support.cors = true` ou `$.get(url, callback, 'jsonp')`, mas vai depender de configurações do servidor.