# Erro Access-Control-Allow_Origin not allowed

Tags: php, cors, xmlhttprequest

Eu estou tentando acessar outro site do meu programa.php, mas está retornando a mensagem:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica?arquivo=47d75bd903c790f2f48b7dbbcc2896c1e98b7dbbcc2896c1e98b7dbbcc2896c1e98b7dbbcc2896c1e98b7dbbcc28. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.yaratecnologia.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.**

Eu mudei o código HTML, mas mesmo assim continua retornando o mesmo erro. Código HTML abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Projeto Yara Tecnologia</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-16">

  <style>html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}
```

A inclusão do comando `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>` **não fez nenhuma diferença!!!**

Existe um lugar correto para escrever este comando no HTML?

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não fez diferença? Do jeito que você postou, seu código deveria ter dado *erro*. Esse arquivo que você postou está de fato sendo processado como um arquivo PHP?

Comment: Na verdade, só postei a parte inicial do código,não o código todo, pois é muito grande. Mas não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro. Somente aquela mensagem "is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: O headers tem que ser adicionados no arquivo `http://177.55.99.146:8080/autenticacao/autentica` e não nesse seu html e essa deve ser a resposta que chega mais perto de resolver o seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12393/3635

Answer (score 2):

O Header deve ser adicionado na página de destino, não na de origem.

Digamos que eu crio uma página `http://meusitedeorigem.com/teste.php`, nesta página eu tenho um script que chama por ajax o endereço `http://siteexterno.com/autentica`, quem precisa ter o Header do `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` é o segundo, é ele quem tem que dizer quem pode acessar ele.

Então não adianta nada adicionar o header na sua página, se o outro site for seu você deve adicionar o header nele, se não for seu não existe nada que possa ser feito, neste caso você deve fazer a requisição para ele com PHP e não com javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta adicionar estes headers:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200' );
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, WCTrustedToken, userId, WCToken, PersonalizationID, AUTHUSER, Primarynum');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
```

Comment: Eu fiz estas inclusões mas não alterou nada. Continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: tinha de ter funcionado, alguma coisa está mal no teu código, os headers estão a ser incluidos no sitio certo? onde a call está a ser feita?

Comment: Pois é....  minha dúvida é: tem algum lugar específico no HTML onde devo incluir este código? Eu estou incluindo na página HTML, onde façoi a chamada para o endereço www.yaratecnologia.com.br...

Answer (score 1):

Cabeçalhos precisam ser enviados antes de qualquer conteúdo. Mude para:

```
<?php
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

E garante que o arquivo esteja sendo interpretado pelo PHP corretamente.