# Angular em pagina PHP ler uma API gerada em php

Tags: php, json, angularjs

Estou falando sobre este exemplo:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php")
   .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
```

<sup>http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_mysql</sup>

Preciso fazer ler essa API:
http://folhacar.com.br/api/listAnuncios?revenda_id=528&cnpj=13733235000134

Eu alterei os campos para os campos relativos e tudo mais porém nada faz dar leitura. Estou errando rude em alguma parte?

Answer (score 1):

O principal problema é que esses dados que você está tentando acessar não estão disponíveis via AJAX a partir de outro domínio. O servidor daquele site (folhacar) precisaria estar configurado para permitir acesso de *cross-origin*. Para mais detalhes e uma possível alternativa, ver *[Como efetuar requisições Ajax, com Jquery, em domínios diferentes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12363/como-efetuar-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ajax-com-jquery-em-dom%C3%ADnios-diferentes)*

> Eu alterei os campos para os campos relativos e tudo mais

Como você não mostrou seu código alterado, não temos como dizer se também havia algum problema nessa parte. Mas resolvendo o primeiro problema que apontei, você logo descobre :)