# Problema com get data no angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Boa noite,

Estou a tentar buscar dados do php através do Angular.js mas não está a funcionar. Quando vou clicar na categoria não abre a próxima página onde serão mostrados os dados.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    require_once("../funcoes/funcoes.php");

    $result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes WHERE menu = :menu AND activo = :activo ORDER BY pos ASC");
    $result->bindValue(':menu', 'Comer', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->bindValue(':activo', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        $result_anex = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM colecoes_anexos WHERE id_mae = :row_id AND seccao = :seccao");
        $result_anex->bindParam(':row_id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result_anex->bindValue(':seccao', 'thumbnail', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result_anex->execute();
        $row_anex = $result_anex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($row);

    }
?>
```

**Controlller**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('comer_categorias', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_categorias_comer.php").success(function (data) {
        $scope.comer = data;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-content ng-controller="comer_categorias">
    <h1 ng-repeat="comer_cat in comer">{{comer_cat.id}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Provavelmente sua requisição está sendo negada porque é para outro domínio. Ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12363/como-efetuar-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ajax-com-jquery-em-dom%C3%ADnios-diferentes e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisição-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis

Answer (score 0):

Qual é o erro?

tente fazer assim

```
$scope.comer = {};

$scope.GetData = function () {
$http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_categorias_comer.php").success(function (data) {

    $scope.comer = data;

}).error(function(data){
console.log(data);
})

}
```