# Após ação ajax, dados não são salvos no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou capturando a latitude e longitude através do plugin geolocation do Cordova, e após isso armazeno em duas variáveis e depois, através de uma requisição ajax, transfiro estes valores para um script PHP onde estou salvando os dados em uma tabela chamada mapa. O problema é que ele executa o código ajax, retorna informação de sucesso, mais nada no banco é salvo... Não consigo encontrar o erro.

PHP:

```
if($_GET['acao']=='btnfinaliza'){

$latitude = $_GET['tlatit'];
$longitude = $_GET['tlongt'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO mapa (lat, lng) VALUES ('$tlati','$tlong')";

$re = mysql_query($SQL, $serve);
}
```

Ajax:

```
$('#btn_finaliza').on('click', function(){

        var Cap = function(position){
            var coord = position.coords;
            var tlatit = position.coords.latitude;
            var tlongt = position.coords.longitude;
            $tlati = $('tlatit');
            $tlong = $('tlongt');
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "get",
                            url: $server+"/conecta.php",
                            data: "latitude="+$tlati+"&longitude="+$tlong+"&acao=btn_finaliza",
                            success: function(data) {
                                intel.xdk.notification.alert('Problema cadastrado', '', 'ok'); 
                            }
                        });

        }

        });
```

Comment: faça: `mysql_query($SQL, $serve) or die(mysql_error());` e veja se aparece algum erro

Comment: olá, não retornou nenhum erro...

Answer (score 2):

Você deve pegar no php pelos mesmo nomes que enviou pelo js, `$_GET['latitude']` e `$_GET['longitude']`

```
data: "latitude="+$tlati+"&longitude="+$tlong+"&acao=btn_finaliza
```

mude para:

```
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO mapa (lat, lng) VALUES ('$tlati','$tlong')";
mysql_query($SQL, $serve) or die(mysql_error());
```

Não utilize as funções mysql_* já foram removidas no php7 prefira o MySQLi ou PDO.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Por que consultas SQL parametrizadas(nome = ?) previnem SQL Injection?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63447/91)

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo conselho! Vou adaptar! Alterei o código, mais ainda não está salvando. A função retorna sucesso, ou seja, a mensagem 'Problema cadastrado' está aparecendo, porem, ainda não está salvando...

Comment: @G.Vilela você olhou no banco p ter certeza?

Comment: já sim, não salva nada...

Comment: @G.Vilela, faz um `echo $SQL` veja o que retorna

Comment: no console apareceu este erro: Requisição cross-origin bloqueada

Comment: @G.Vilela, veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12363/91) você pode testar a lógica do php, so passando os valores na url se quiser

Answer (score 0):

Após cerificar a sintaxe do código, descobri o erro... 
Estava faltando um _ no código php. Estava

```
if($_GET['acao']=='btnfinaliza')
```

mais deveria ser:

```
if($_GET['acao']=='btn_finaliza')
```

Após a correção, o código funcionou e os dados foram salvos no banco conforme esperado.
Agradeço pela ajuda e, vou seguir as recomendações!