# É possível resolver o erro No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no front-end?

Tags: javascript, api, cors

Pessoal preciso consumir uma API de terceiros com Javascript, não tenho acesso para liberar o CORs na API.. e está aparecendo este erro como consigo resolver ?
tenho a seguinte requisição utilizando o axios:
obs: quando faço a requisição no postman está dando certo.

```
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: {},
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Não dá pra resolver no front-end. Você vai precisar construir um proxy no seu back-end e fazer a requisição por meio dele.

Comment: Ou usar um proxy público como https://corsproxy.github.io/

Comment: Como funciona esse corsorigin.me ? é so colocar antes da url ? tentei aqui não deu certo.. vlw..

Comment: Como ele diz no próprio site, não tem como garantir a disponibilidade do serviço. Por isso é melhor ter seu próprio proxy. [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12393) tem um exemplo simples em php.