# Requisição cross-origin bloqueada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Olá, eu estou tentando carregar uma página de uma outra aplicação dentro de uma div da minha aplicação utilizando o load do jQuery mas a minha aplicação não está carregando a página e mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro:

Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto

(Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

Código da view da minha aplicação:

```
<div id="pagina">
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#pagina").load("http://localhost:4576/");
    </script>
}
```

Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se essa pergunta o ajuda : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis

Comment: Depois vc responde a sua pergunta como você fez no iis.

Answer (score 4):

[A solução mais elegante que conheço](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290385/1314276) implementa um *Attribute* que permite aceitar a requisição dependendo da *Action* ou do *Controller* chamado. Não recomendo registrar o *Attribute* globalmente.

## 1. Crie um novo *Attribute*

```
public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

## 2. Registre a *Action* com o *Attribute*

```
[AllowCrossSite]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

## 3. Instale o [`CorsProxy.AspNet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CorsProxy.AspNet/) para compatibilidade retroativa com o IE

```
Install-Package CorsProxy.AspNet
```

### 3.1. Configuração da rota com o `CorsProxy`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Coloque antes da rota padrão.
        routes.EnableCorsProxy();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

### 3.2. Configuração dos *Bundles* com o `CorsProxy`

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    // Coloque os demais scripts relativos ao jQuery aqui
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-corsproxy-{version}.js"));
        ...
    }
}
```

## 3.3. Implemente um *Handler* para requisições CORS

```
public class CorsProxyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var url = context.Request.Headers["X-CorsProxy-Url"];
        if (url == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 501;
            context.Response.StatusDescription =
                "X-CorsProxy-Url was not specified. The corsproxy should only be invoked from the proxy JavaScript.";
            context.Response.End();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            context.Request.CopyHeadersTo(request);
            request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;
            request.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
            request.UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;

            if (context.Request.AcceptTypes != null)
            request.Accept = string.Join(";", context.Request.AcceptTypes);

            if (context.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                request.Referer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

            if (!context.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(request.GetRequestStream());

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.CopyHeadersTo(context.Response);
            context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
            context.Response.StatusCode =(int) response.StatusCode;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;

            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null && response.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("X-CorsProxy-InternalFailure",  "false");

            var response = exception.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response != null)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                context.Response.StatusDescription = response.StatusDescription;
                response.CopyHeadersTo(context.Response);
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);

                return;
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = 501;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = exception.Status.ToString();
            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(exception.Message);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            context.Response.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 501;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = "Failed to call proxied url.";
            context.Response.AddHeader("X-CorsProxy-InternalFailure", "true");
            var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(exception.Message);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            context.Response.Close();

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; }}
}
```

### 3.4. Configuração a chamada Ajax

Antes do seu `.load`, configure o jQuery com o seguinte:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXhr) {
    if (!window.CorsProxyUrl) {
        window.CorsProxyUrl = '/corsproxy/';
    }
    // only proxy those requests
    // that are marked as crossDomain requests.
    if (!options.crossDomain) {
        return;
    }

    if (getIeVersion() && getIeVersion() < 10) {
        var url = options.url;
        options.beforeSend = function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CorsProxy-Url", url);
        };
        options.url = window.CorsProxyUrl;
        options.crossDomain = false;
    }
});
```

[A explicação original está aqui](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/04/how-to-use-cors-requests-in-internet-explorer-9-and-below/).

Answer (score 2):

Amigo já resolvi esse problema apenas adicionando a tag:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

no meu web config..

segue o web.config completo:

```
<location path="Sample.txt">
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: O único porém dessa solução é que libera requisições *cross-origin* para todas as *Actions* de todos os *Controllers*. Não acho muito seguro usar isso.