# CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer um acesso de minha máquina local a um servidor e estou recebendo esta resposta:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Porém usando o Postman eu consigo - este são os requisitos do servidor:

```
// Estes cabecalhos sao necessarios no CORS
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
```

Meu código:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var submit = true;

    if( submit )
    var form = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: form,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });

    return false;
});
```

Alguem me da uma luz!

Comment: Não conheço o contexto da sua aplicação já passei por isso e o que me salvou foi essa extensão chrome: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related]. As extensões de navegador tem menos restrições para realizarem requisições. No final das contas, para fazer `delete` tive que tornar a minha aplicação uma extensão.

Comment: Davi Aragão, funcionou, muito obrigao, mas queria muito entender o motivo de nao consegir acessar sem este app e oq este app faz que consegue liberar o acesso

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Na sua requisição do `$.ajax`, você pode passar o `crossDomain: true` conforme abaixo:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: form,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

ou

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Porém, antes disso, certifique-se se o **CORS** está habilitado também no seu servidor. Para que tudo funcione, o CORS deve estar habilitado em ambos, cliente e servidor.

Se estiver utilizando Node.js, pode adicionar direto no seu retorno como no código abaixo:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

:)

Comment: eu tentei com o "crossDomain: true" mas nao consegui ainda, nao tenho node instalado, passei o header por "php" e mesmo assim nao esta funcionando, apresenta o mesmo erro :(

Comment: No seu servidor php você adicionou algo como: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ? segue link http://leocaseiro.com.br/acesso-externo-php-ajax-crodomain/

Comment: Sim CORS
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

Comment: @BrunoGomes tenta setar esse comando antes do ajax (jQuery.support.cors = true;) ele na teoria faz a mesma coisa no que passei acima mais olhando no código ele faz um esquema diferente .. enquanto isto vou dar uma olhada no código da extensão que você falou que deu certo acima :))

Comment: funcionou kkkkk vlw!!!

Comment: Fico feliz de ter dado certo :)) vou atualizar o post ..

Comment: Como faço isso sem usar jQuery?

Comment: @AllanAndrade de uma olhada aqui :) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3251/30045

Comment: na onde eu coloco **jQuery.support.cors = true;** ?

Comment: @GuilhermeAlves você deve utilizar no entrypoint do seu script antes da chamada ajax que você desejar :)

Answer (score 0):

O problema deve ser permissão de uso de CORS no seu apache, experimente colocar isso no arquivo **.htaccess**:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```