# Autenticação de Usuário em AngularJs com API Rest em Java/Jersey

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, jersey, jax-rs

Estou desenvolvendo o módulo de autenticação de usuário na minha aplicação e estou tento alguns problemas para acessar a API, recebendo erro 403.

Da forma antiga que estava fazendo, quando enviava a requisição para o serviço, ele me retornava corretamente os dados que precisava sem dar erro algum (e continua funcionando, pois mantive o controller antigo para comparação). Na época, pra fazer funcionar, tive que incluir no web.config o CorsFilter para que o acesso fosse permitido (já que são domínios diferentes).

Agora com o controller novo, já utilizando alguns recursos de autenticação (estou me baseando no exemplo do site do [jasonwatmore](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx)), ele me retorna o erro 403 conforme abaixo:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/GameService/webserver/usuario/realizaLogin. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Se volto para o controller antigo, funciona. Se coloco no novo dá o erro, mesmo sendo o mesmo serviço a ser chamado.

loginController.js (controller novo):

```js
    ggApp.controller('loginController', loginController);

    loginController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];
    function loginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {


        var vm = this;
        vm.usuarioLogin = {};

        (function initController() {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
        })();

        this.login = function() {
            var usuario = {
                    email: vm.usuarioLogin.login,
                    senha: vm.usuarioLogin.senha
            }

            vm.dataLoading = true;
            AuthenticationService.Login(usuario, function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(usuario);
                    $location.path('/home');
                } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

serviceAutenticacao.js (utilizado somente no novo controller):

```js
ggApp.factory('AuthenticationService', AuthenticationService);

    AuthenticationService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'LoginUsuario'];
    function AuthenticationService($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout, LoginUsuario) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = Login;
        service.SetCredentials = SetCredentials;
        service.ClearCredentials = ClearCredentials;

        return service;

        function Login(usuario, callback) {

            var promise = LoginUsuario.login(usuario); <-- Aqui dá o erro

            promise.$promise.then( 
                function success(response)
                {
                    callback(response);
                });
        }

        function SetCredentials(usuario) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(usuario.email + ':' + usuario.senha);

            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    usuario: usuario,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        }

        function ClearCredentials() {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic';
        }
    }
....
```

usuarioController.js (controller antigo e que funciona):

```js
ggApp.controller("usuarioController", ['$scope', 
                                       'LoginUsuario', 
                                       'Cadastro', 
                                       'VerificaEmail', 
                                       '$location',
                                       function($scope, LoginUsuario, Cadastro, VerificaEmail, $location) {

    $scope.erro = false;
    $scope.mostraMensagem = false;
    $scope.mensagemErro = "teste";
    $scope.classeErro ='alert alert-danger';

    this.usuarioLogin = {};

    $scope.setClasseErro = function() {

        if ($scope.erro) {
            $scope.classeErro ='alert alert-danger'
        } else {
            $scope.classeErro = 'alert alert-success'
        }
    };

    this.realizaLogin = function() {

        var usuario = {
                email: this.usuarioLogin.login,
                senha: this.usuarioLogin.senha
        }

        var promise = LoginUsuario.login(usuario); <--- Mesma Chamada não dá erro!!

        promise.$promise.then( 
                function success(usuario)
                {
                    if (usuario.id > 0) {
                        $location.path("home");
                        $cookieStore.put("autenticado",true);
                    } else {
                        $scope.erro = true;
                        $scope.mensagemErro = "Usuário não encontrado!";
                    };
                    $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
                    $scope.setClasseErro();

                },
                function error(value) {
                    $scope.erro = true;
                    $scope.mostraMensagem = true;
                    $scope.mensagemErro = "Erro: " + value.status;
                }
        );


    };
                                         ....
```

`serviceUsuario.js` (serviço utilizando `$resource` utilizado pelos dois controllers, novo que acessa através de outro serviço e antigo que acessa direto):

```js
var servicoLogin = angular.module('servicoUsuario', ['ngResource']);

servicoLogin.factory('LoginUsuario', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/GameService/webserver/usuario/realizaLogin', {}, {
      login: {method:'POST'}
    });
  }]);

  }]);
```

`web.xml` (do server):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>GamerGaragemService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.gamergaragem.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webserver/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

UsuarioRecurso.java (classe do serviço):

```java
@Path("/usuario")
public class UsuarioRecurso {

    private static String persistenceUnitName = "hibernateGG";

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/realizaLogin")
    public UsuarioModel realizarLogin(UsuarioModel usuario){

        SimpleEntityManager simpleEntityManager = new SimpleEntityManager(persistenceUnitName);

        IUsuarioBusiness usuarioB = new UsuarioBusiness(simpleEntityManager);

        Usuario usuarioRetorno = usuarioB.login(usuario.parseTo());

        if (usuarioRetorno != null)
            usuario.parseInto(usuarioRetorno);

        return usuario;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Talvez te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86342/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu consegui descobrir o ponto do problema. Quando eu seto um header diferente em $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic'; ele causa esse erro. No meu server eu preciso colocar em algum lugar dizendo que ele tem que aceitar esse tipo de header?

Comment: Acredito que sim, no entanto não sei dizer aonde seria e nem o que seria.

Comment: Colega o seu código não tem as configurações de Segurança com Spring Security ou outro. O que você está usando? Do jeito que está só vai funcionar sem autenticação mesmo.

Comment: @Shura16 deixa eu ver se eu entendi, pra alterar o header pra trabalhar com token ou outro tipo de autenticação eu preciso que no server ele "entenda" esse header novo, certo? Eu procurei por exemplos para me basear, mas tudo que eu tentei até o momento me deu o mesmo erro. Tem alguma dica/url/tutorial/exemplo pra me passar?

Answer (score 1):

Para que a parte de segurança funcione a mesma deve ser configurada no servidor.

Isso pode ser feito com JAAS usando Spring Security, Apache Shiro ou outras soluções.

Existem vários tutoriais na internet (explicar aqui ficaria muito grande), a maioria deles em inglês, mas temos alguns em português por exemplo:

1. [Spring Security (antigo mas dará uma idéia)](http://www.loiane.com/2010/01/tutorial-comecando-com-spring-security/)
2. [Apache shiro](http://aeloy.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/exemplo-de-utilizacao-do-framework.html)
3. [Spring Security + AngularJS (em inglês)](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)