# JavaScript Requisição POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>

$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "http://192.168.1.140:8080/vectis/account/vialaser/webservice/cliente/consultarCliente" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( "http://192.168.1.140:8080/vectis/account/vialaser/webservice/cliente/consultarCliente", { cpfCliente: term } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {

    alert('Passou');
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tenho esse código, porém olhem o que ele retorna:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.1.140:8080/vectis/account/vialaser/webservice/cliente/consultarCliente.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 422.

Ele não entra no alerta de jeito nenhum.

Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Com ajax:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery('#conversion-form').submit(function(){             
    event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:8080/vectis/account/vialaser/webservice/cliente/consultarCliente",

    data: 'cpfCliente=078.736.879-29',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) { alert("Success"); },
    error: function(data) { alert('Failed!'); },

});
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="conversion-form">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="cpfCliente" name="cpfCliente" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="botaoenviar"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button id="botaoenviar" name="botaoenviar" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou)

Comment: Não ajudou.....

Comment: O que esta parecendo esse erro é que o link que você esta tentando fazer a requisição possui acesso controlado, e você não tem autorização para acessar...

Comment: Mas eu coloco um breakpoint na minha aplicação e ele chega...

Comment: Olha se esse link pode te ajudar... esta ingles
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: mas acho que segue a mesma do colegar Lucas ali...

Comment: Esse plugin provavelmente vai te salvar: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Poís é, mas meu clientes não vão poder instalar o plugin, certo?

Comment: CORS sempre precisa ser autorizado pelo servidor, não no cliente. Se o serviço que estiver consumindo não permitir, por meios normais você não conseguirá fazer nada. Existe como adicionar o plugin no chome ou usar uns proxy, porém não é assertivo nem praticavel.

Comment: Editei a pergunta da implementação com ajax, acontece o mesmo.

Comment: Por isso sugeri como duplicada, é um problema bem comum e que já possui muitas discussões.

Comment: @Alisson, $.post e $.ajax são basicamente a mesma coisa - ambos são requisições ajax.

Comment: @Alisson, quando se esta debugando no localhost o cors fica barrado independente de como esta configurado o back, quando estiver em producao o cors so vai estar bloqueado se o back nao der permissao, entao nao, seus clientes nao terao que instalar, apenas voce para debugar no localhost

Comment: Agora não retorna nenhum de XMLHttpRequest cannot load, porém ainda entra no alerta de erro

Answer (score 1):

O `alert` é disparado porque o POST request foi concluído com sucesso e a resposta do servidor foi 422, ou seja, houve uma resposta do servidor embora o código 422 represente um erro.

O erro "XMLHttpRequest cannot load." é uma resposta do browser perante a resposta do servidor, que retornou o código 422, logo a função que é passada como parâmetro para o método `done` será executada.

Por razões de segurança, os navegadores restringem solicitações HTTP de origem cruzada iniciadas a partir de scripts. Sendo assim, como o seu aplicativo web usa `XMLHttpRequest`, só poderia fazer solicitações HTTP para seu próprio domínio.

O seu domínio de origem não é o mesmo que o domínio da requisição, entretanto é possível o compartilhamento de recursos de origem cruzada (CORS).

Veja o fluxo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Considere o retângulo verde o domínio da sua aplicação (localhost) e o retângulo rosa o domínio (192.168.1.140) da requisição HTTP.

O fluxo é inciado por uma chamada XHR feita pelo JavaScript, a requisição será executada normalmente se:

- Usar os métodos GET, HEAD ou POST;
- É uma requisição GET sem cabeçalhos customizados;
- É uma requisição HEAD sem cabeçalhos customizados;
- É uma requisição POST com o header `Content-type` padrão (application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data ou text/plain) sem cabeçalhos customizados.

Ao contrário das solicitações simples (discutidas acima), as solicitações "preflighted" enviam primeiro uma solicitação HTTP pelo método OPTIONS para o recurso no outro domínio, a fim de determinar se a solicitação real é segura para ser enviada, sendo assim o servidor tem a oportunidade de determinar se deseja aceitar um pedido nestas circunstâncias.

O servidor por sua vez responde com os cabeçalhos `Access-Control-*`, por exemplo:

```
// indicação de que o dominio "example.com" tem permissões para aceder ao recurso
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com

// indicação de quais métodos serão permitidos na requisição real
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS

// indicação de quais cabeçalhos serão permitidos na requisição real
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type

// indicação de que quanto tempo os resultados de uma solicitação "preflight" podem ser amazenados em cache
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

[Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) poderá ver tudo sobre esse assunto. A informação acima pode ser verificada utilizando, por exemplo, a console do Google Chrome, na tab "Network".

Com base na informação acima, o problema só será resolvido quando a requisição for considerada segura pelo servidor onde se encontra o recurso (que no seu caso é o servidor 192.168.1.140), ou seja, é necessário alterar o cabeçalho da resposta do servidor.

Eu não posso ajudar nessa parte porque não sei qual linguagem é utilizada, se foi implentado ou não alguma framework, etc... Entretanto a solução passa por aceitar uma solicitação HTTP pelo método OPTIONS e retornar os cabeçalhos que vimos acima.