# Múltiplos domínios Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, json, htaccess

Tenho uma página que serve alguns dados em formato JSON com base nos dados recebidos do banco, porém preciso liberar acesso para que a versão mobile também possa obter tais dados, como posso colocar mais que um domínio no  Access-Control-Allow-Origin do htaccess?

Tentei o código abaixo porém não funcionou

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(dominio.com|m.dominio.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas atende sua dúvida?

Comment: Até o momento, não

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso:

```
<FilesMatch "\.json$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(dominio.com|m.dominio.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**Atualizado:**

Ou tente usar o `addHeader`,

`response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

> `*` serve para dar acesso para todos os domínios

Para dar acesso a domínios específicos utilize:

> `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com");`

Comment: O erro persiste No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa pergunta e vê se te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou

Comment: A solução apresentada para htaccess nessa pergunta pede para eu liberar o acesso para qualquer um usando o *, e eu não gostaria de usar tal método.

Comment: Eu mostrei um exemplo para liberar o acesso manualmente para alguns domínios.

Comment: É só colocar o addHeader dentro do If mod.headers? E ir adicionando mais linhas conforme os domínios?

Comment: Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com"

Comment: Usando dessa forma só é possível adicionar 1 domínio

Answer (score -2):

Talvez não seja a resposta que você quer, mas não seria possível usar JSONP? Talvez seja mais simples que tentar mexer no htacess para diferentes casos.