# Retorno JSON com erro: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

Estou com um problema no retorno JSON, e já pesquisei e não consegui solução.
Tenho a seguinte requisição:

```
  var url = 'http://zcash.flypool.org/api/miner_new/t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63?callback=?';

  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    alert(data);
  });
```

E dá o seguinte erro:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63:1:10
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema, ou me dar uma luz de como resolver?

Obrigado!

Comment: O erro dá nessas linhas de código mesmo?

Comment: No console do Firefox, do retorno no JSON.  `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement[Learn More]  t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63:1:10`

Comment: Tenta tirar o `?callback=?` do final da url pra ver o que acontece...

Comment: Dá outro erro: `Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://zcash.flypool.org/api/miner_new/t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).`

Comment: Isso já responde. Você não tem permissão para obter os dados a partir de outro domínio. Leia [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86342/5878) e [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3183/5878) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Humm, obrigado. Mas teria algum jeito de recuperar os dados desse link: `http://zcash.flypool.org/api/miner_new/t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63` ?

Comment: Tentei ler em python: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`, ou seja, acesso publico bloqueado, embora seja possivel ler via browse (ai é só usar a 'criatividade') :-)

Comment: Não entendi essa 'criatividade' kkkkk Mas não exista nenhum jeito: salvar em localStorage, e filtrar depois?

Comment: Cara, eu consegui obter os dados usando o `file_get_contents` do PHP, tu pode fazer um ajax pra um servidor local e desse servidor fazer a requisição e depois retornar pro javascript... é um jeito...

Comment: @JuniorNunes obrigado pela dica! Consegui resolver assim =)

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio, cria uma resposta resumida de como tu conseguiu resolver e marca como solução pra ajudar as próximas pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida!! valeu!

Answer (score 1):

O erro está acontecendo porque você não definiu uma função para callback. Vou dar um exemplo de como você resolve isso.

```
function teste(r){console.log(r);}
var url = 'http://zcash.flypool.org/api/miner_new/t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ9FV6sYFzYg6H63?callback=teste';

 $.getJSON(url, function(data){
   alert(data);
 });
```

Comment: Amigo, aqui não funcionou: `Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://zcash.flypool.org/api/miner_new/t1UjazwJJnrUGoPh4GJYJ‌​9FV6sYFzYg6H63. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).`

Comment: Agora é problema de cross-origin, resolveu o erro que você citou, existem tópicos aqui no stackoverflow referentes a esse problema, você pode dar uma pesquisada para entender melhor.