# Erro Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: web-service, codeigniter, axios, vue-resource

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma requisição de um servidor para outro para realizar um cadastro, mas sempre me é retornado esse erro:

> Failed to load http://dominio_da_api/services/criarConta: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://dominio_que_solicita.com.br' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Minha requisição está assim:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'token': 'meu_token'
    }
};
this.$http.post('http://dominio_da_api/services/criarConta', this.dados, config).then(response => {
```

Utilizei uma extensão do chrome para testes do CORS, quando ela esta habilitada funciona normalmente, mas quando desabilito me gera esse erro. Estou usando o CodeIgniter e para as requisições o Vue-resource, tbm utilizei o axios, mas me retorna o mesmo erro

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou)

Comment: Esses cabeçalhos CORS devem estar na resposta do servidor, não na requisição do cliente

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema um tempo atrás com isto tentando fazer requisições na API do Google Maps, e ocorria este erro no front-end (Vuejs2), porém através do Postman funcionava.

Não entendi o problema, porém resolvi isto por realizar primeiramente uma requisição na minha própria API do back-end que possuía no projeto em Laravel, e o Laravel fazia a requisição para a API do Google Maps, e depois retornava para o meu front-end.

Desta forma, o meu front-end permanece sempre acessando o meu back-end, e o back-end se torna o responsável por acessar API(s) de terceiros.

Espero que tenha ajudado.