# Erro ao consumir webservice em c#

Tags: c#, ajax, web-service

Estou fazendo um web service em c# ,para consumir os dados dele via javascript(sem ser uma aplicação feita no asp.net ou qualquer tecnologia .NET ,quero usar apenas html e javascript).

Meu web service ficou configurado assim:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PhoneGap : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

E meu ajax ficou assim :

```
function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST'
        //Caminho do WebService + / + nome do metodo
        , url: "http://localhost:3458/PhoneGap.asmx/HelloWorld"
         , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            , dataType: 'json'
            //Abaixo adicione as variáveis caso haja alguma.
            , data: ''
            , success: function (data, status) {
                //Caso não ocorra nenhum tipo de erro:
                $('.valor').text(data.d);
            }
            , error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
                //Caso ocorra algum erro:
                $('.valor').html('Ocorreu um erro');
            }
    });
}
```

Quando vou fazer o teste para consumir o Hello Word do web service esta dando erro(Obs: Ententei acha se dava para usar o Web service local mente para teste mas não encontrei nada usando apeans html e ajax)

Erro:

**Failed to load http://localhost:3458/PhoneGap.asmx/HelloWorld: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que a chamada funcione de uma origem diferente, você deve deve configurar o Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Para um projeto ASP.Net com ASMX, a seguinte seção no Web.Config pode resolver seu problema:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
     </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Porém, para que consiga chamar o método do WebService ASMX a partir do Javascript, a classe do WebService deve conter o atributo [ScriptService], assim:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService] // AQUI
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

Só uma **observação**: é realmente necessário usar ASMX para esse projeto? Os webservices ASMX são uma tecnologia legada e não deveriam ser considerados em novos projetos. Recomendo dar uma pesquisada no [ASP.Net Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api) ou mesmo [WCF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf).

Comment: Deu certo ,muito obrigado,realmente acho que não precisa ser o ASMX ,como estou pesquisando formas de buscar meus dados que estão na minha aplicação feita em ASP.NET ,ainda não decidi se vai ser realmente esse.