# Consumir este JSON pois estou encontrando um erro

Tags: javascript, json, cors

Eu tenho este JSON: [API JSON](https://thaleshenrique38.000webhostapp.com/products.json)

Porém quando vou consumi-lo obtenho este erro

```
VM414 index.html:1 Access to fetch at 
 'https://thaleshenrique38.000webhostapp.com/products.json' 
 from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
    If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 
    'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

O que devo fazer, pelo que entendi estou sem permissão como eu posso me dar esta permissão para consumir a API.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86342/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resou)

Answer (score 1):

Você não conseguirá obter uma resposta deste WS pois ele não especifica o tipo de acesso resposta ou seja, o **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***, impedindo que você tenha acesso direto á ela como especifica a documentação

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Portanto você deve utilizar um proxy cors para esta chamada, para isto você pode contar com esta API para resolver seu problema

> https://cors.io/

Comment: Em adição, caso não queira utilizar um proxy você pode setar os headers para permitir chamadas CORS. Na reposta do Sampaio Leal você pode acompanhar possíveis soluções de acordo com o que você usa