# Como consumir uma api Soap (do cadsus) via javascript(Browser)?

Tags: javascript, soap, xmlhttprequest

Hoje consigo consumir as apis do CadSus pelo dotnet c#. Porém, agora preciso consumir estas mesmas apis(cadsus) via javascript(tela), mas, estou recebendo o seguinte erro quando faço a seguinte requisição via browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://servicos.saude.gov.br/' from origin 'http://localhost:4566' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
POST https://servicos.saude.gov.br/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema e sabe resolve-lo?

meu código é o seguinte:

```
<script>
function soap() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = $('#url').val();
        var SOAPEnvelope = $('#SOAPEnvelope').val();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'https://servicos.saude.gov.br/cadsus/PDQSupplier');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(SOAPEnvelope);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145490/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86342/3774)

Answer (score -3):

Pela mensagem de erro apresentada, está faltando um header, Access-Control-Allow-Origin adiciona:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```