# Como resolver problema de "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: javascript

Não estou sabendo resolver o problema de `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. O que fazer para funcionar corretamente?

```js
function calc() {
 
 var cepDestino = document.getElementById( 'cepDestino' ).value;
 if(cepDestino.trim() != ""){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  request.open('GET', 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep='+cepDestino, true);
  
  request.onload = function() {
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    document.getElementById('bairro').value(data.bairro);
    document.getElementById('cidade').value(data.cidade);
    document.getElementById('estado').value(data.estado);
   } else {
    // Não deu certo    
   }
  };
  
  request.onerror = function() {
    // A conexão nem sequer deu certo
  };
  
  request.send(); 
 }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="cepDestino">CEP Destino</label>
  <input class="input" type="text" name="cepDestino" id="cepDestino" >
  <div id="bairro"></div> - <div id="cidade"></div> - <div id="estado"></div>
</p>

<p>
  <input class="button" type="button" id="calcular" value="Calcular" onclick="calc();">
</p>
```

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior Eu não estou usando jquery. Não tem nada haver meu problema com esse existente.

Comment: Descuple, marquei a pergunta errada: Duplicada relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta API tem como parâmetro o tipo de retorno, para trabalhar com CORS e JSON, você deve especificar `formato=jsonp` na URL do request.

Fora isto, temos outros problemas, o primeiro é o envio sincrono do AJAX, raramente isto é uma boa ideia.

uma tag `<div>` não possui uma propriedade `value`, e mesmo que tivesse ela não é um método e sim uma propriedade, em todo caso você deve setar o `textContent` da div.

```js
function calc() {
 
 var cepDestino = document.getElementById( 'cepDestino' ).value;
 if(cepDestino.trim() != ""){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  request.open('GET', 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep=' + cepDestino + '&formato=jsonp', false);
  
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4) {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    document.getElementById('bairro').textContent = data.bairro;
    document.getElementById('cidade').textContent = data.cidade;
    document.getElementById('estado').textContent = data.estado;
   } else {
    // Não deu certo    
   }
  };
  request.send(); 
 }
}
```

```css
label {
 width: 100%;
 display: inherit;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 3em;
 margin-top: 41px;
}
.input, #descricao {
 width: 100%;
 height: 111px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 4em;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #ECF0F1;
}
.button {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: xx-large;
 height: 116px;
 background-color: #2CC36B;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 76px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="cepDestino">CEP Destino</label>
  <input class="input" type="text" name="cepDestino" id="cepDestino" />
  <div id="bairro"></div> - <div id="cidade"></div> - <div id="estado"></div>
</p>

<p>
  <input class="button" type="button" id="calcular" value="Calcular" onclick="calc();">
</p>
```