# Adicionar cabeçalho na função getJson do JQuery

Tags: jquery, getjson

É possivel adicionar algum cabeçalho na função $.getJson do jQuery?

Estou tendo problemas de cross-origin e li em alguns lugares que a adição de algumas informações de cabeçalho podem resolver esse problema.

Comment: Cross Origin deve ser permitido no servidor. Sabe se o endpoint que está querendo consumir tem essa permissão?

Comment: Qual o seu problema, especificamente? alguns sites tem bloqueios de requisições de fora, por isso, pode haver erros de Cross Origin.

Comment: Eu acho que sim, pois só da problema e uma das chamadas do getJson (essa é a que retorna mais dados)

Comment: Tento captura dados do site http://spcultura.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ mas quando tento capturar os agentes da problema de cross-origin

Comment: Você está tentando capturar dados em json?

Comment: Sim, capturando em JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) é um simplificado de:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Portanto, para setar um cabeçalho, é possível uma chamada como:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authority", authorizationToken);
    },
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```

Porém, se o problema é CORS, a solução somente será se o endpoint (servidor) permitir o CORS. Veja essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/32827) para entender o que ele é e [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis/3251#3251) que contém um exemplo de como permitir. Mas se você não tiver autonomia para mudar alguma configuração no servidor, nada poderá ser feito no front-end.

Comment: Utilizando getJSON a requisição fica rodadno por cerca de 2:30 minutos e retorna o erro 504, utilizando ajax com o cabeçalho `request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` a requisição é recusada de forma instantânea e retorna o erro 404. Isso pode ser indicativo que o servidor que não permite cross-origin?

Comment: 404 é not found. A URL da requisição está correta? Quando não permite, no console do browser ele diz a requisição foi bloqueada pelo cors.

Comment: A URL está correta, é a mesma que usei em getJSON, até conferi o erro pra ver se estava igual e estava. Também está dizendo que foi bloqueado por CORS mas mudou o código de erro de 504 para 404.

Comment: 404 é not found, 504 é tempo esgotado e 401 é não autorizado. Geralmente quando o problema é somente CORS, o status code é 401.

Comment: A quantidade de dados a ser buscada é bem grande, eu havia tentado limitar a quantidade de dados a ser buscada e assim funcionou. Tem como aumentar o tempo limite?

Comment: Existe o time out do Ajax, mas vai servir só se passar de 15 minutos (que o valor padrão que ele aguarda). Mas se o site retorna retornar timeout depois de um certo tempo, volta ao mesmo caso do cors, não tem o que fazer :/

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)