# Dúvida com acesso a API - usando Angular - typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic, woocommerce

Montei um site para estudo de uma loja 
WooCommerce, ativei a api e gerei as chaves.

Na raiz do site em adicionei no .htaccess, será que está no local correto?:

```
# Permite acesso ao pacote Font Awesome
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|woff)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Mais estou tendo o erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código completo para teste:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  WooCommerce: any;
  products:any[];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  this.WooCommerce = WC({
       url:"http://wooionic.comajudacoletiva.com.br/",
       consumerKey:"ck_899d1c4011cab2bde1f04cd52704c248f155ecdc",
       consumerSecret:"cs_cc90feaf8467c0a53679be89f137557cdc7acbe5"
     });

        this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then( (data) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
         // this.products = JSON.parse(data.body).products;
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que sendo [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic) seja possivel deixar mais permissivo se for em um `webView` (app mobile), mas já que você tem controle sobre o site, bastaria remover o `FilesMatch`, ficando apenas assim no teu .htaccess:

```bsh
# Permite requisições de qualquer origem
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Claro que isto vai liberar qualquer origem de acessar, recomendo que leia esta excelente resposta do @mgibsonbr:

- [Requisição Ajax cross-domain com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3251/3635)

Note que se estiver usando IIS (sim PHP roda no IIS através do Fast-CGI ou CGI) então não deve usar .htaccess e sim crie na pasta raiz do subdominio um arquivo chamado `web.config` ao invés de um `.htaccess`, tome cuidado pode ser que já exista um `web.config`, neste caso faça um backup e edite o original, deve ficar algo como:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Já fiz isso é não funcionou

Comment: @itasouza eu olhei os headers de resposta no teu site http://wooionic.comajudacoletiva.com.br/ e não esta retornando o Access-Control-Allow-Origin, o .htaccess esta na raiz do site wooionic.comajudacoletiva.com.br ?

Comment: sim, está na raiz

Comment: @itasouza verifica o nome nome se esta `.htaccess`, com duas letras c e duas letras s, depois verifica o conteudo no FTP, talvez vc não tenha atualizado corretamente. Se não der me avisa que irei fazer alguns testes ;)

Comment: detalhe, quando eu falei raiz do site eu quis dizer dentro do subdomínio "wooionic.comajudacoletiva.com.br" e não dentro do httpdocs

Comment: eu adicionei agora em httpdocs  e fora dela

Comment: Teu servidor é IIS né? @itasouza eu tinha pensado que era Apache

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58433/discussion-between-itasouza-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Eu fiz o ajuste que você me passou, já adicionei o web.config na raiz do site e também na raiz do subdomínio, removendo o “.htaccess” porque o servidor e Windows. Eu ainda não testei para saber se está liberando o acesso remoto, de qualquer forma agradeço a ajuda.