# Problema com headers Axios | Aplicação => Laravel + vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

estou tentando fazer uma requisição com axios, mas não consigo sempre recebo o seguinte erro:

```
admin:1 Failed to load http://minhaurlencurtada: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mv.test' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Já tentei colocar os headers diretamente no axios mas não obtive sucesso, quando a requisição é  feita via php não tenho problemas então descartei problemas no servidor, mas depois de muita busca e tentativas com headers, baixei uma extenção no navegador chrome que se chamada "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ela fez funcionar normalmente sem o erro, ai descartei os parâmetros passados na url, agora fica minha duvida o que é preciso para fazer uma requisição a uma api de dentro de um componente Vue.js?

Comment: Você pode encontrar uma explicação detalhada sobre o problema [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis/3251#3251) basicamente você está fazendo uma requisição para um servidor diferente do que serve seus arquivos da aplicação

Comment: Ja fiz tudo que ai contem, e nada! meu problema está em resolver isso no vue.js, pq se fizer fora do componente funciona,ja tentei com axios, vue-resource e ajax, mas não obtive sucesso!