# Msxml3.XMLHTTP Em qual caso é utilizado?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Estava lendo o seguinte tópico: [Requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)

Lá eles mostram a seguinte linha de código:

```
var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];
```

Sei que pra `Firefox`, `Opera 8.0+`, `Safari` = `XMLHttpRequest();` é o basicão

Pra `Internet Explorer` = `Msxml2.XMLHTTP`

Quais navegadores utilizam `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` e `Msxml3.XMLHTTP`?

Atualmente aqui na empresa utilizamos requisições `Ajax` somente com `XMLHttpRequest()`, `Msxml2.XMLHTTP` e `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` e queria saber se seria necessário acrescentar tambem o `Msxml3.XMLHTTP`

Andei dando uma pesquisada a respeito e não encontrei nada, se puderem me dar uma luz eu ficaria muito grato...

Answer (score 1):

### **XMLHttpRequest**

O objeto nativo dos browsers modernos

### **Msxml2.XMLHTTP**

Também válido como *MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0* conforme o *knowledge base* do [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms537505%28v=vs.85%29#_ID) esse objeto ActiveX introduzido com a MSXML2, representa hoje um *fallback* para as versões 5.x e 6.0 do Internet Explorer.

### **Msxml3.XMLHTTP**

Na verdade, deveria ser *Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0* porque, ao que parece, não existe um *ProgID* válido que corresponda a *Msxml3.XMLHTTP, pois o objeto foi de certa forma "unificado" e o versionamento específico sufixado (Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0, Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0...)

Ainda conforme o artigo do MSDN acima, esta definição é o *fallback* para versões anteriores ao Internet Explorer 7.

### **Microsoft.XMLHTTP**

Internet Explorer 5, como se alguém ainda se lembrasse dele :p

Por fim, uma versão aprimorada desse seu código, também vinda do canal de discussões do MSDN com link acima, caso o objeto nativo não exista:

```
if( !window.XMLHttpRequest )
{
  window.XMLHttpRequest = function()
  {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch( e ) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch( e ) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch( e ) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch( e ) { }
    throw "Could not create XMLHTTP object.";
  }
}
```

Isso porque conforme [este artigo](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314160956/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) em um dos blogs do MSDN, a abordagem em que você lista todos os possíveis objetos e em seguida itera pela coleção e instancia àquele com maior *ProgID*, é errado. E os motivos apresentados, aqui traduzidos, são:

- **Compatibilidade** – Nós fazemos nosso melhor para manter a compatibilidade ao longo das versões da MSXML, porém, versões iniciais, como a MSXML 3 e MSXML 4 foram implementadas no "oeste selvagem" do surgimento do XML e muita coisa foi aprendida e melhorada ao longo desse tempo.

Adicionalmente, o MSXML 5, para as Aplicações do Microsoft Office foi criado com foco específico para cenários do Microsoft Office. Algumas vezes por questões de design ou de implementação é preciso alterar coisas que afetam o comportamento da MSXML entre suas diferentes versões

Ao iterar uma coleção de objetos da MSXML você abre sua Aplicação para o risco potencial  de "esbarrar" em uma dessas diferenças inesperadamente.

- **Robustez** - Nos não podemos corrigir todos os bugs encontrados em cada uma das muitas versões da MSXML, por isso, criamos a MSXML6 (mais recente<sup>[1]</sup>) e a MSXML3 (a mais largamente desenvolvida<sup>[1]</sup>), as quais receberam grandes investimentos.
- **Custos dos Testes** – Quanto mais versões da MSXML sua Aplicação potencialmente dependa significa mais versões as quais você deve testá-la antes de entregá-la a seus clientes.

<sup>[1]</sup> Nota do Tradutor: Até a data do artigo em 2006