# Array de JavaScript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho o seguinte Input no meu arquivo `.html`

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="option[]" id="option[]">
```

Sempre que o usuário clicar no campo de `+` no botão ao lado, ele cria outro `input` igual esse.

Estou tentando pegar esse valor com JavaScript da seguinte maneira:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    if( (inputs[i].name).indexOf('option')>-1 && inputs[i].value!="") {
        inputs ++;
    }
}
```

E depois preciso passar esse valor por POST e passar para a minha pagina `.php` , 
que lá eu recebo da seguinte forma:

```
    if(isset($_POST['option[]'])){
        $cc = array($_POST['option[]']);
}
```

Comment: Você não pode ter mais de um campo com o mesmo id. E isto aqui: `(inputs[i].name).indexOf('option')>-1 && inputs[i].value!="";`? Qual é a intenção? Você não está fazendo nada aí, não atribui o valor a nenhuma variável. A intenção é ter uma condicional/`if`?

Comment: Desculpe, cortei a parte do `if` .. no caso fica assim `if( (inputs[i].name).indexOf('option')>-1 && inputs[i].value!="") {inputs ++;}`

Comment: Ok, incluí essa informação na pergunta. E acho que encontrei o problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você dá `inputs++` dentro do `if`, isso não funciona, pois `inputs` é uma lista de campos, e não um número. Se quer contar quantos inputs estão preenchidos, pode criar outra variável para isso:

```
var optionsPreenchidas = 0;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    if( (inputs[i].name).indexOf('option')>-1 && inputs[i].value!="") {
        optionsPreenchidas++;
    }
}
alert(optionsPreenchidas);
```

Isso se você quiser somente contar as opções preenchidas. Se quiser guardar os valores delas, vai precisar de uma array:

```
var optionsPreenchidas = [];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    if( (inputs[i].name).indexOf('option')>-1 && inputs[i].value!="") {
        optionsPreenchidas.push(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
alert(optionsPreenchidas.join(','));
```

Para passar isso para o PHP, bastaria submeter o form, não precisa de JavaScript nenhum. Só que a página recarrega. Se a intenção for fazer isso sem recarregar a página, é preciso usar ajax. Para fazer uma requisição ajax com JS puro, veja a pergunta ***[Requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)***, tem uma explicação bem completa lá.

Comment: bfavaretto, vou testar ai amanha eu posto se deu certo! Obrigado pela ajuda! :D

Comment: Deu Certoo! Obrigado pela Atenção!!