# Fazer trocas de textContent em larga escala com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Eu tenho uma página na qual eu quero que a cada evento seja trocado o `textContent` de um `<h1>`, um `<p>` e uma `<img>`.

Pensei em includes de php ou Json. Não sei.

(É muito conteúdo, por isso pensei em Json)

Comment: O que você chama de "evento"? Eventos de teclado, mouse, etc, ou é outra coisa? Por acaso você se refere a "quando acontecer X no browser, busca-se mais conteúdo no servidor via Ajax, no formato JSON"?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não, é um evento de click. É uma página que demonstra 6 produtos e tem um submenu para trocar cada uma das 6, dai quero manter a estrutura da pagina e so trocar o titulo paragrafo e imagem de demonstração

Comment: É, então é um caso de uso típico de Ajax mesmo. Se você nunca usou Ajax, sugiro dar uma lida no assunto. Dá pra fazer com jQuery (mais fácil) ou [com JavaScript puro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/215) (nada do outro mundo, só um pouquinho mais trabalhoso). Vou delinear os passos numa resposta (com jQuery, para ela não ficar muito extensa), se tiver alguma dúvida mais específica favor editar a pergunta com os detalhes relevantes.

Comment: @mgibsonbr É que eu não sei jQuery ainda. Estou buscando ficar full em js puro. Seria legal se pudesse fazer m JS. E outra pergunta: tem certeza de é Ajax? Por que? E ainda se eu quiser colocar uma transição suave de pagina?

Comment: Se você quer uma visão geral do processo, vai ficar bem mais conciso em jQuery do que em JS puro. Se alguém se dispuser a te responder no formato que você espera, tanto melhor, o que *eu* posso fazer é dar referências adicionais. Quanto ao Ajax, você tem duas alternativas: 1) renderizar a página inteira de novo (i.e. trocar a página toda a cada evento); 2) buscar somente os dados que mudaram usando JavaScript e inserir esses dados no seu local correto. Esse item 2 - que me parece ser exatamente onde você está tentando chegar - é o que chamamos de "Ajax" (javascript asíncrono e xml/json/etc).

Comment: P.S. Eu sei que é "contra a etiqueta do site" responder com jQuery uma pergunta só sobre JavaScript, e peço desculpas por isso, mas no meu entendimento essa pergunta está "em alto nível", não é sobre como executar a etapa X em JS, e sim *quais* etapas têm de ser executadas.

Comment: @mgibsonbr de boa dps eu passo pra JS

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19444/discussion-between-ropbla9-and-mgibsonbr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está gerando uma página com PHP, onde o clique em um elemento (ou alguma outra ação qualquer) deve buscar outros resultados no servidor, a primeira coisa a fazer é especificar *o que* deve ser buscado. Eu costumo fazer isso através de atributos `data-`, mas você pode fazer isso de outras formas se quiser:

```
<ul id="itens"><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul>
<a href="#" id="mais" data-mais="42">Mais itens</a>
```

Daí você intercepta o evento, descobre os parâmetros relevantes para sua consulta, e faz uma requisição Ajax para buscar esse conteúdo (no caso em JSON, mas poderia ser XML ou outro):

```
$("#mais").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var pagina = $(this).data("mais");
    $.getJSON('/buscar/mais/itens.php', { pagina:pagina }, function(dados) {
        // Aqui, "dados" já foi convertido de JSON (texto) para objetos javascript comuns
    });
});
```

Seu servidor deve então receber o `/buscar/mais/itens.php?pagina=42` e retornar os dados no formato JSON. Não tenho experiência prática com PHP, mas sei que você pode fazer isso usando alguma biblioteca ou simplesmente inserindo variáveis PHP dentro de um arquivo de texto no formato JSON (lembre-se de usar o *mimetype* correto):

itens.php

```
{
    "pagina":<?= $pagina ?>,
    "proximaPagina":<?= $pagina + 1 ?>,
    "itens":[
        <?php
            ... (iterar sobre os itens e inserir, no formato JSON)
        ?>
    ]
}
```

Uma vez recebido os dados, tudo o que você precisa fazer é atualizar os elementos da página com os dados recebidos via Ajax. No meu exemplo acima, seria algo como:

```
    $.getJSON('/buscar/mais/itens.php', { pagina:pagina }, function(dados) {
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < dados.itens.length ; i++ ) {
            $("#itens li").eq(i).html(dados.itens[i].valor);
        }
        $("#mais").data("mais", dados.proximaPagina);
    });
```

No seu exemplo, você teria que selecionar os elementos que te interessam e trocar a parte relevante (no `h1` e no `p` você troca o `innerHTML`, no `img` você troca o `src` e talvez também o `title` e o `alt`).

### Referências para executar os passos acima em JavaScript puro:

- Se seleciona um elemento usando `document.querySelector` ou - em browsers mais antigos - `document.getElementById` ou outros métodos relacionados;

  - O `querySelector` recebe uma sintaxe bem semelhante à usada pelo jQuery, vale a pena usar se for uma possibilidade.
- Se seleciona múltiplos elementos usando `document.querySelectorAll` ou `document.getElementsByTagName`, etc;
- Atribui-se um *handler* ao link ou botão através da propriedade `onclick`. Outros componentes aceitam *handlers* diferentes (você falou em um submenu, certo? seria um `select` ou outra coisa?);
- [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/215) se mostra como fazer uma requisição Ajax com JavaScript puro;
- O `getJSON` do jQuery já converte o JSON para objetos JavaScript pra você, mas se você fizer o Ajax à mão você também tem que fazer essa conversão manualmente. Isso é feito da forma:

  ```
  var dados = JSON.parse(respostaDoAjax_emTexto);
  ```
- O método `.data` do jQuery corresponde mais ou menos a se consultar um atributo `data-` do elemento no DOM. Ou seja:

  ```
  var pagina = $(elemento).data("mais");
  ```

  É mais ou menos a mesma coisa que:

  ```
  var pagina = parseInt(elemento.getAttribute("data-mais"), 10);
  ```
- Dado um elemento (obtido pelos métodos descritos acima), você pega seus filhos através do atributo `children`. Então você pode iterar sobre eles.