# Substituto de $.getScript JQuery para Javascript

Tags: javascript

Achei uma consulta de CEP na internet, mas não gostaria de usar jQuery. É possível alterar `$.getScript` jQuery para JavaScript?

```
var cepDestino = document.getElementById( 'cepDestino' ).value;
if(cepDestino.trim() != ""){
        $.getScript("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep="+cepDestino, function(){

            if (resultadoCEP["tipo_logradouro"] != '') {
                if (resultadoCEP["resultado"]) {
                    document.getElementById( 'bairro' ).value = unescape(resultadoCEP["bairro"]);
                    document.getElementById( 'cidade' ).value = unescape(resultadoCEP["cidade"]);
                    document.getElementById( 'estado' ).value = unescape(resultadoCEP["estado"]);
                }
            }       
        });
    }
```

**NOVO CÓDIGO**

http://jsfiddle.net/dg5bdxyh/

Comment: Você vai precisar fazer uma requisição AJAX, veja essa pergunta [Requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis).

Answer (score 1):

Usando **JavaScript** puro sim, por meio de uma requisição **Ajax**.

Retorna um **jSON**.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep='+cepDestino, true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Deu certo... Use a variável abaixo para obter os dados
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // Não deu certo    
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // A conexão nem sequer deu certo
};

request.send();
```

---

Para retornar os campos em determinados lugares faça:

`document.getElementById('bairro').value(data.bairro)`

Para você ver como está retornando os nomes dos campos, coloque depois do `var data`, dentro do `if` um `console.log(data)`. Faça a requisição e veja no **console** do Inspect Element do Chrome.

Daí você sempre usa: `data.nome_do_campo`.

Comment: Ai para eu mostrar por exemplo o nome do ``bairro`` na DIV ID bairro, como fazer?

Comment: Atualizei o Poste.

Comment: Apareceu esse erro ``MLHttpRequest cannot load http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=javascript&cep=%22+cepDestino. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.meusite.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.``

Comment: Meu código estava errado no LINK. Veja de novo, tinha uma aspas a mais... no `request.open`.

Comment: Quando carrego aparece essa mensagem ``Unexpected end of input`` e quando clico no botão ``<input class="button" type="button" id="calcular" value="Calcular" onclick="calc();">`` Mensagem do console ``calc is not defined``

Comment: Coloca seu código novo no seu POST para vermos.

Comment: Blz, vou colocar.

Comment: Veja http://jsfiddle.net/dg5bdxyh/

Comment: Você não consegue fazer esse teste no JsFiddle, faz no Localhost.

Comment: Estou fazendo diretamente no meu site, coloquei no JsFiddle para te enviar o código.

Comment: Então, tem uma `}` faltando no final da função `calc` na que você passou pra mim no JsFiddle.

Comment: Isso, achei agora...rsrs. O ``Access-Control-Allow-Origin``, continua.

Comment: No Stack tem várias perguntas sobre isso que está acontecendo com você. Acredito ser outro assunto... iria se estender muito aqui.

Comment: Estou até agora tentando achar uma solução, mas sem sucesso. Você tem muito mais conhecimento que eu, por gentileza, me ajuda.