# PHP pedir confirmação antes de deletar

Tags: php, javascript

Oi

Em um curso que estou fazendo a pessoa não ensinou como fazer para apagar um registro no bd primeiro pedir uma confirmação antes de deletar. Então eu fiz esse código.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include_once("../../controle/conexao.php");
include_once("../../controle/seguranca.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM ordem_producao WHERE op_clientes = '$id'";
$resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);   
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_consulta);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=../../paginas/layout/dashboard.php?link=12'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Este cliente não pode ser apagado, pois existem transações.\");
            </script>"; 
    }else{              
    }?>
```

Minha duvida agora como eu coloco a mensagem de deletar no else, e também o código `DELETE FROM cadastro_clientes WHERE id='$id';`

Obrigado

Comment: Você quer que o usuário confirme para deletar algo no banco de dados através do bloco do `else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugestão de como fazer

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0) {
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=../../paginas/layout/dashboard.php?link=12'>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Este cliente não pode ser apagado, pois existem transações.\");
            </script>"; 
}else{

        $sql = "DELETE FROM op_clientes WHERE id = '$id'";
        $executa = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(“o cliente foi excluído”);
        </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

<sub>nota: Me abstenho em comentar sobre a logística ou segurança e métodos técnicos. No entanto, recomendo estudar o modelo de negócios e o básico sobre lógica de programação e as ferramentas em uso. Analise primeiramente o business model, se realmente é bom o que está fazendo (ex: excluir cliente permanentemente)</sub>

Comment: Concordo com a "nota". Acredito que NUNCA deva deletar nada, se não para poupar espaço ou compactar (ou seja, armazenar de outra forma o mesmo dado), inclusive remover a permissão. O "ideal", para mim, é criar um dado para `Status`, ao menos booleano. Da forma que 1 seria um usuário ativo (padrão) e 0 um usuário/dado que é "excluído". Isso também pode ser melhor para backups e monitoramento e exclusões acidentais (ou afins). Isso é o que geralmente uso (não sendo booleano), deve haver outras soluções, até melhores. Mas, realmente o fato é excluir o dado diretamente é importante a ser notado.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação

Answer (score 5):

Este tipo de validação, habitualmente é feita no lado cliente. Você pode fazê-la com JavaScript no evento onclick da tag do seu html, que chama seu método.

Ex.

```
<a href="deletar?id=1" onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar este registro?')">Excluir</a>
```

Comment: E se o javascript, por algum motivo, estiver desativado no navegador?

Comment: Bom isso é muito incomum, visto que 99% das páginas é feita com JS, porém você pode fazer um método recursivo, que chama a mesma página com um novo parâmetro e colocar uma validação antes desse método de deletar. Ex.  if (isset($_GET['confirmado])){ // seu método de deletar}

Comment: Obrigado vou testar aqui.

Comment: Raramente um usuário "normal" está com o JS desligado. Apenas complemento (mas fora da questão da pergunta!), é ideal incluir um `token`/`código` de segurança junto ao `id`, por exemplo: `deletar?id=1&token=123456789`. O tal código pode ser gerada de maneira pseudo-randômica, no servidor. Depois, quando o usuário confirmar, o servidor verifica se ambos os códigos coincidem (tanto o enviado pelo cliente, quanto o armazenado em session pelo servidor). Isso evita que alguém lhe envie um link (principalmente encurtado) para deletar algo. Porque se enviar `deletar?id=1` não haverá o token. ;)

Comment: @Inkeliz Boa dica, cara

Answer (score 2):

Antes de tudo quero dizer que essa linha no bloco do `else`

```
</script>";
```

está errada e causaria um erro de interpretação no código. Você tinha que ter colocado a aspa antes do primeiro byte `'<'`: `"</script>"`, <s>e de qualquer maneira causaria um erro de interpretação já que não há um statement que precisa de uma string</s> (se fosse no JavaScript, seria diferente, `"</script>"` seria retornado no console, ou se fosse igual à `"use strict"` iria ao modo estrito, ou ignorado; **edit**: no PHP a string é ignorada). Use `echo` para jogar uma string no HTML.

---

Eu entendi que você quer exibir uma caixa de confirmação para deletar algo no banco de dados. Nesse exemplo vou mostrar a função `confirm` do JavaScript.

`confirm` é global, ou seja, é localizado no objeto `window`. Ao chamar essa função -_- a página é travada enquanto o usuário não confirma (não responde) a caixa de confirmação que foi aberta com a própria função `confirm`, e assim que for confirmada retorna `true` se a resposta do usuário foi "Sim", ou `false` se a resposta foi "Cancelar", ou algo do tipo. Então com essa função podemos fazer uma condição tipo `if(confirm("Quer me responder?")) alert("Então você quer me responder"); else confirm(":(");`, ou `confirm("Quer me responder?") && alert("Uau! Você é incrível! :D Herói!")`.

O objetivo é que o usuário responda "sim" à caixa de confirmação e que algo seja removido de uma tabela do banco de dados. Você não pode fazer isso diretamente do JavaScript, por isso vai ter que usar AJAX, que vai executar o arquivo ao lado do servidor (o arquivo *.php). Vai ampliar muito a resposta se eu explicar sobre isso, mas deixo o link de uma [pergunta respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167) que vai te ajudar.

E outra coisa, não vejo sentido em usar PHP para construir a página HTML e executar JavaScript. Para responder sua pergunta, experimente colocar isso dentro do seu `else`.

```
echo '<script>
    if(confirm("Deseja remover o *?")) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.get("GET", "delete.php?id='. $id .'", true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4) {
                if(this.status === 200) {
                    alert("Deletado.");
                }else{
                    /* Erro ao requisicionar o arquivo *.php */
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.send();
    }
</script>';
```

E o arquivo delete.php deveria ter um id especificado no URL -. -, na verdade existe o método `POST` além do `GET`. Não vou explicar muito isso porque a pergunta é um pouco ampla, mas vamos ver se compreende:

```
<?php

// se o id foi declarado no URL, e.g: *url*/?id=num
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // pega e converte o id no url para número (caso vier como uma string, mas impossível de acontecer, eu creio)
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    // obs: isso é inseguro se você não
    //detectar o usuário que está deletando algo do db
    // remova algo do db usando $id
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Duro que nestas aulas que aprendi o professor não utilizou ajax. usar ele agora mais vai me confundir do que me ajudar.

Comment: @Junior Entendo. AJAX é mais usado para não ter a necessidade de recarregar a página.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizo a confirmação via javascript, mas nesse caso somente para confirmar a ação, não faz verificações. De qualquer forma é essencial para envitar ações acidentais.

```
onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja editar este registro?')"
```