# Como fazer que uma alteração seja impressa na view sem refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function atualizarTarefas() {
       var url = "institucional";
       jQuery("institucional#entregas").load(url);
   }
   setInterval("atualizarTarefas()", 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Vai precisa de ajax

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: [Requisição Ajax com Javascript puro sem APIs](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/91) ou com [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @MagicHat Essa pergunta é um pouco diferente por causa do contexto Code Igniter. A resposta é mais simples que na pergunta marcada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É simples:

Na sua chamada `load` no JavaScript utilize a função `site_url()` do helper Url para passar o link correto para a função do controller.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#minha_div").load("<?=site_url('institucional/tarefas/')?>");
```

**Controller**

```
class Institucional extends CI_Controller {

     public function tarefas() {
        echo "Seu conteúdo";
     }
  }
```

ou

```
class Institucional extends CI_Controller {

    public function tarefas() {
       $this->load->view("listagem_tarefas");
    }
 }
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: obrigado! valew mesmo deu certo aqui