# Como posso separar essa string javascript em duas variáveis php?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Segue o código____________________________________

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Map On</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Localizacao: " + position.coords.latitude+","+ position.coords.longitude;


}
</script>

<?php 
  $teste = "<script>getLocation()</script>";
  echo $teste;
  $latAqui = explode(" ", $teste);
  print_r($latAqui);
?>
```

```
Retorno até o presente momento_______________________________________

Localizacao: -22.3588937,-47.3859919

Array ( [0] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

Só vai conseguir passar esse dado via Ajax.

Quando o PHP renderiza a página ele escreve literalmente que `$teste = "<script>getLocation()</script>";`. Para ele `"<script>getLocation()</script>"` é simplesmente uma string. Não tem nenhum significado e não executa nada.

Quem executa o Javascript é o browser depois que o HTML puro gerado pelo PHP está pronto e é renderizado para o usuário final. Nesse momento o PHP não tem mais poder nenhum sobre a página.

O que você pode fazer é criar uma função que execute esse comando e envie o resultado via AJAX para o seu projeto PHP.

O AJAX é separado em duas etapas. O envio do browser feito com Javascript que você pode ler mais sobre no próprio stackoverflow: [Requisição Ajax com Javascript puro (sem APIs)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3167/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis)

E a API no PHP que vai receber essa requisição. Aqui tem um pequeno tutorial falando a respeito também: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-cadastro-com-php-ajax-e-jquery/28046

Não é um processo trivial. Vai precisar estudar um pouco para entender como realizar até porque são chamadas assíncronas, mas é a única forma de pegar a localização do usuário pela API do Browser.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo ou um site para que eu possa ver, por favor?

Comment: @JulioRamos complementei a resposta. Entenda que não é um processo trivial. Não dá para colocar o código completo do projeto aqui porque é preciso mexer em várias pontas, mas é a única forma de realizar essa verificação. 

Sem depender de integração com o browser só se fizer por IP. Mas vai precisar consultar um serviço externo ou comprar uma base de IP geolocalizados.

Comment: Por ip não é possível, ele retorna ips da região, pois o ip é dinâmico.

Comment: A base de IP pega o prefixo da região. Geralmente tem precisão no nível das cidades. 

Mesmo o usuário tendo IP dinâmico ela consegue acertar porque pega o prefixo do local.

Usando as API's de geolocalização do browser só passando por AJAX mesmo. Você consegue passar dados do PHP para o browser diretamente na página, mas jamais consegue passar do Javascript pro PHP sem ser por outra conexão como AJAX e Websockets por exemplo.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro remova a localização da função e deixe assim:

```
return position.coords.latitude+","+ position.coords.longitude;
```

Depois:

```
 $teste = "<script>getLocation()</script>";
 echo $teste;
 $latAqui = explode(",", $teste);
 echo($latAqui[0]);
 echo($latAqui[1]);
```

Comment: Recebo o seguinte erro : Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\testeGEOIP.php on line 35

Comment: Qual é a linha 35?

Comment: Essa aqui:  print_r($latAqui[1]);

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Ainda esta com erro, amigo ^-^

Comment: De um print_r($latAqui). Qual o retorno?

Comment: Array ( [0] => )

Comment: e no echo($teste), qual o retorno?

Comment: -22.3588937,-47.3859919

Comment: Minto, o resultado da function é nulo

Comment: Editei novamente a resposta

Comment: E lembre-se. A variavel teste precisa ter conteúdo

Comment: @LucasTorres o valor que ele espera é o retorno da função `getLocation`.  Como esse script só é executado no browser ele acaba pegando literalmente a string que está definida no PHP que não tem valor nenhum para ele. 

Não vai funcionar dessa forma.