# Busca no banco a partir de option

Tags: php, html

Eu preciso que ao selecionar uma opção em um *option*, ocorra uma pesquisa no banco sem sair da página e que mostre o que foi retornado através dessa busca e que preencha campos com os resultados. Eu já tenho o layout montado e o script para o banco, mas não sei como fazer quando for selecionada uma opção no *option*.

Comment: Vai precisar de ajax.

Comment: Teria uma sugestão de como fazer?

Comment: Coloca um `EventListener` no `onChange` do _select_. Este _listener_ deve fazer uma chamada ajax para o _server-side_ (PHP) e quando a chamada for completada deve preencher os campos com o retorno recebido do _server_.

Comment: Você pode usar [ajax puro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3167/91) ou [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) quando montar esse código anexe ele ao evente (on)Change() ou seja a cada vez que uma option for selecionada o javascript vai fazer uma requisição para o php ele retornará algo(texto, json etc) o último passo é tratar esse retorno.

Answer (score 1):

**Não há resposta exata para sua pergunta**

Como diz o comentário do @rray, você vai precisar de `AJAX`.

**O que é AJAX?**

`AJAX` é uma tecnologia que possibilita fazer uma requisição ao servidor sem ter que atualizar a página, que presumo que é exatamente o que você quer fazer.

**Como uso AJAX?**

Bom, é relativamente simples. Esse tipo de requisição existe no navegador através do `xmlHttpRequest`, que funciona mais ou menos assim:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Essa parte é executada quanddo a requisição retornou do servidor
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //Verifica se a requisição foi um sucesso
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Aqui é aonde você faz as coisas que você precisa depois que contatou o servidor;
    }
};

//Parametro 1 -> Nome do método a ser chamado no servidor
//Parametro 2 -> Nome da página aonde está o parâmetro 1
//Parametro 3 -> Define se é síncrono ou assíncrono
//É nesse método que você efetivamente FAZ requisição
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```

No caso, sei que você tem um `option`, então você poderia fazer algo como: (note que meus exemplos são genéricos, pois não tenho como saber seu código, nem o que você quer com precisão)

```
document.getElementByID('seuElemento').onchange = function (){
    requisicaoAjax();
}

function requisicaoAjax(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           alert('Ei, foi um sucesso!');
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "pagina", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Talvez você já tenha ouvido falar da biblioteca `JQuery` (não estou dizendo que você deve usar, apenas que ela existe). Ela encapsula os `xmlHttpRequest`, e fica deveras bonitinho, olha:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'pagina/metod',
    data: 'seusParametros',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        //foi um sucesso!
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        //deu pau, trate seu erro aqui...
    }
});
```

Enfim, isso é apenas uma minúscula introdução. Recomendo que leia [isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão e explicação, irei tentar!