# Usar `await` fora de função assíncrona causa erro de sintaxe

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando fazer uma função que espere a resposta, mas o console aponta um erro:

> ```
> var cota = await getJSON();
>            ^^^^^
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
> ```

O meu código é:

```
async function getJSON() {
    var options = {
        url: "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all",
        method: 'GET'
    }

    await request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
            return body
        };
    });
};

var cota = await getJSON();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vale dizer que a sua função está incorreta. O resultado de `request` jamais será retornado por `getJSON`, já que o `return` está dentro do [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback) da função `request`, e não da própria `getJSON`. Nesse caso, como você está trabalhando com um *callback*, creio que seja mais interessante retornar uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) diretamente:

```js
function getJSON() {
  const options = {
    url: 'https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(body);
      }
    });
  });
}
const cota = getJSON()
  .then((body) => {
    console.log('Recebi o body:', body);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Algo deu errado:', error);
  });
```

Note que, no exemplo acima, o `async` não foi necessário, já que o operador `await` não foi utilizado em nenhum momento dentro da função `getJSON`.

Se você quiser utilizar função assíncrona, pode utilizar a API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) — que é uma alternativa nativa para a biblioteca `request`. Saiba mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369072/69296). Assim:

```js
async function getJSON() {
  const response = await fetch('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all');
  const body = await response.json();

  return body();
}
const cota = getJSON()
  .then((body) => {
    console.log('Recebi o body:', body);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Algo deu errado:', error);
  });
```

Agora, vamos ao erro:

> ```
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
> ```

O [operador `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) só pode ser utilizado dentro de funções marcadas como `async`, conforme a mensagem de erro deixou — pelo menos a meu ver — bem claro.

Portanto, você não pode utilizar o `await` fora de funções assíncronas, o que torna o seguinte excerto do seu código inválido:

> ```js
> var cota = await getJSON();
> //         ↑↑↑↑↑
> //       INVÁLIDO, como está FORA de uma função marcada com o `async`
> ```

Portanto, você tem duas opções:

1. Utilizar o [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), já que toda função assíncrona retorna uma `Promise`. Fiz esse exemplo acima. Ou:
2. Utilizar uma outra função assíncrona. Algo assim:

```js
async function getJSON() {
  const response = await fetch('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all');
  const body = await response.json();

  return body();
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const body = await getJSON();
    console.log('Recebi o body:', body);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Algo deu errado:', error);
  }
})();
```

No caso acima, utilizei uma IIFE assíncrona.