# Quais os principais tipos aceitos pela API Fetch para o corpo da requisição HTTP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, http-request, fetch

Sei que a posso [utilizar a API `fetch` para realizar requisições HTTP pelo *browser*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/369072/69296).

E sei que posso utilizar a propriedade `body` para configurar o corpo da requisição. Mas gostaria de entender melhor quais tipos posso utilizar nessa propriedade.

Além disso, qual é a relação de cada tipo aceito com o cabeçalho *Content-Type* que o servidor espera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A propriedade `body` é responsável por definir o corpo da requisição a ser efetivada pelo [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). O tipo de dado que você pode passar a essa propriedade é variado, de modo que aceita:

1. **[`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)**
2. **[`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)**
3. **[`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)**
4. [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
5. [`BufferSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BufferSource)
6. [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream)

Os três primeiros são os mais comuns. É relativamente raro utilizar `Blob`, `BufferSource` e `ReadableStream` no dia a dia, mas saiba que, se precisar, eles existem.

Abaixo explicarei, entre `FormData`, `URLSearchParams` e `USVString`, qual é o mais adequado para cada situação.

### Utilizar `FormData` (`multipart/form-data`)

Utilize o tipo `FormData` na propriedade do corpo da requisição quando o servidor aceitar requisições cujo *Content-Type* seja `multipart/form-data`. Esse *Content-Type* é comumente utilizado quando algum dos campos do corpo é um arquivo.

A interface de uso é extremamente simples, uma vez que o construtor [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) aceita como argumento um elemento `HTMLFormElement`, que terá os campos serializados.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Seu elemento <form>:
const form = document.querySelector('#my-form');

fetch('https://path.to/resource', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new FormData(form)
})
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Note que, quando se passa uma instância `FormData` à propriedade `body`, o cabeçalho *Content-Type* já é definido automaticamente como `multipart/form-data`.

## Utilizar `URLSearchParams` (`urlencoded`)

Utilize o tipo `URLSearchParams` para requisições na qual o *Content-Type* esperado é `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Seu elemento <form>:
fetch('https://path.to/resource', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    field1: 'Value1',
    fieldN: 'ValueN'
  })
})
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Quando se utiliza `URLSearchParams` em `body`, o cabeçalho *Content-Type* é definido automaticamente como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Observe que o construtor `URLSearchParams` não aceita uma instância de formulário diretamente (assim como `FormData` faz). Você pode passar um objeto com chaves e valores, que serão corretamente serializados (conforme demonstrado no exemplo acima). Uma outra opção, [conforme documentado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20pass%20it%20directly%20to%20the%20URLSearchParams%20constructor%20if%20you%20want%20to%20generate%20query%20parameters%20in%20the%20way%20a%20%3Cform%3E%20would%20do%20if%20it%20were%20using%20simple%20GET%20submission.), é passar uma instância de `FormData` ao construtor `URLSearchParams`, então a serialização de um formulário inteiro também se torna trivial:

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('form#my-form');
const urlEncodedBody = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(myForm));

// Passe `urlEncodedBody` para a propriedade `body` da requisição...
```

## Utilizar `USVString` (string como corpo da requisição)

O tipo [`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) nada mais é que uma diferente implementação de strings dos browsers. Ignorando a parte técnica (que pode ser consultada na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)), é basicamente o tipo primitivo `string` do JavaScript. Desse modo, é o tipo que deve ser utilizado quando, por exemplo, precisa-se enviar conteúdo em formato `application/json`.

Um exemplo:

```js
fetch('https://path.to/resource', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    field1: 'Value1',
    fieldN: 'ValueN'
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Note que o [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) retorna o primitivo `string` do JavaScript. Antes da requisição ser executada, a implementação converterá o tipo `string` do JavaScript para o `USVString`.

Observe que como passar uma string para a propriedade `body` é ambíguo (pode representar diversos tipos de *Content-Type* diferentes), o navegador não tem como inferir esse cabeçalho corretamente. Desse modo, supondo que queremos fazer uma requisição cujo `body` é do tipo `application/json`, precisamos fornecer o cabeçalho explicitamente.